# Logic App Storage Blob Trigger on new Blob only

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure logic app that triggers every time a blob is added or updated. Is there any way I can stop it from triggering when a blob is updated? I only need it to run when a blob is created. Alternatively, is there a way I can check if it is being triggered on an update and cancel it from running?

Comment: You could potentially move the blob to another container after processing it.

Answer (score 2):

The best I can think of is to replace the Storage Blob trigger with a "When a resource event occurs" trigger. It can guide you through setting up an Event Grid subscription to the Blob Created event of the storage account (See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureeventgrid/#when-a-resource-event-occurs)). This will have the added benefit of having the logic app respond almost directly to the event instead of having to rely on the polling mechanism of the blob trigger.

[image]